# How secure is using a changing hash, like the time?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, md5

If i do something like this in php:

```
$server_key = md5( '00' . date( 'i' ) . '09' );
```

and submit an html form with the date (seconds) encoded in md5 (plus the hash before and after):

Is this easy to crack?

Comment: Secure against what? What is it used for? I would guess not, especially if the attacker found out what you are doing.

Comment: Used for a password primarily. Secure against attacks, like brute force.

Comment: That's what I'm asking ... would this be easy to figure out.

Comment: Well, a 32-character password would be secure against a dumb brute-force attack attempted over HTTP, but so would shorter passwords (network latency really limits this, even if the site does not rate-throttle). However, if an attacker knew your system, they could much-more-easily guess how you generated it. Additionally, if they were able to capture a few samples and crack the MD5, they might be able to reverse your technique.

Comment: I still don't understand, what you're trying to do here. It seems to me that you want to create an encryption key on the server by digesting the current date/time. How is this key used and what is it supposed to encrypt? What does this have to do with HTML form submission? Are you planning to encrypt something on the client in the same way? What does this have to do with passwords which you mentioned in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm assuming the use of the MD5 hash value over seconds as authentication method because of the information in the comments below the question.*

---

No, this is not considered secure, because

- it breaks [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle): the algorithm itself should be considered public and anybody can implement an algorithm without obtaining a secret/key;
- it is pretty easy to iterate through all seconds of e.g. a year and test all possibilities on the server;
- the time is already captured by an attacker observing the creating the connection or can be easily guessed based on simply looking at the clock;

That MD5 is also insecure doesn't even come into play here (and it would be exceptionally hard to apply an attack on this protocol).

Comment: *"and it [would**n't**] be exceptionally hard"*, right?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Nope, it *would* be exceptionally hard because the attacker doesn't control the input to the hash, and the hash is of limited size. There is no need to attack MD5 because the other issues are much easier to attack.

Comment: @ArtjomB. ... the *input* of the hash is of limited size (the hash is of course *always* of limited size) :P